# React-Native: TouchableOpacity Rendering issue

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have some issue while rendering TouchableOpacity

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';


class Button extends Component {
  render() {

    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress= {this.props.onPress}
        style = {style.buttonStyle}>
        <Text style = {style.textStyle}>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const style = {
  textStyle:{
    fontSize: 16,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#007aff',
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    borderColor: '#007aff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5

  }
}

export {Button};
```

this is the code for my button component and My button looks like this when i render it 
[image: The Button]

And i used the same component In Login Component and it worked fine...
**Expected Button:**
[image: This is the button which i expect to render]

Comment: does the button's container have flex:1 ?

Comment: You might have applied `alignItem:center` in your first button's parent container?

Comment: @JeremyLee Yes the one which is working fine...the button with the render issue is not in any container